# Hyper-v and openstack

Tags: openstack, hyper-v

Can Hyper-V be integrated with the last release of Openstack which is Kilo , if not the case , which is the best release to integrate them together. thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Yes!  Here is the hypervisor [support matrix](http://docs.openstack.org/developer/nova/support-matrix.html) for OpenStack and [the docs](http://docs.openstack.org/kilo/config-reference/content/hyper-v-virtualization-platform.html) for getting started.

[Cloudbase](https://cloudbase.it) is actively developing OpenStack with Hyper-V so all of this is changing and improving over time.

Note:  I work at Microsoft on the Hyper-V team.

Answer (score 0):

You should be fine ...
Have you seen this 
https://wiki.openstack.org/wiki/HypervisorSupportMatrix